# Getting Wrong URL By submiting a Form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am doing some sample application on spring security.

This is my controller :

```
 @Controller
 public class MainController {

 ......
 ......

 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView editPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "User edit Form - Database Interaction");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName("editpage");
    System.out.println("getting edit page");

    return model;

}
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateCredentials(@RequestParam(value= "username", required= false) String username , @RequestParam(required=false)String password) {
    System.out.println("Username= "+username+"  password= "+password);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Credential Edit Operation");
    model.addObject("message", "You are successfully updated your credentials");
    model.addObject("edited", "TRUE");
    model.setViewName("editpage");
    System.out.println("executed updateCredentials POST method");

    return model;

  }

 }
```

This is my editpage.jsp where i am submitting a form;

```
     <%@page session="true"%>
  <html>
     <body>
<h1>Title : ${title}</h1>
<h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
<br>
<c:if test="${ edited ne 'TRUE'}">
    <form action="/edit" method="POST" id="editForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" />

    <a  href="javascript:crSubmit()" >Edit</a>
</form>
</c:if>
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
<script>
    function formSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
    }
    function crSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("editForm").submit();
    }
</script>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
    <h2>
        Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
            href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
    </h2>
</c:if>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Now the issue I am facing is While I am submitting the form the URL I am getting is wrong.  like below ;

http://localhost:8080/edit

for which i am getting 404 response code.

but the actual URL of the project is

http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurity/edit

How it is happening ?

Am I wrong some where ?

please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend current context path to the url (`SpringSecurity` is your context). Try this:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit" method="POST" id="editForm">
  ....
```

Comment: Yeah @Igor that is solved now correct URL is coming. But now I am getting the response code 405.

Comment: make sure your `/edit` handler mapped with `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: 405 is "Method Not Allowed". for `<form method="POST"` it means that there no `/edit` mapped with `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: Try with another mapping instead of `/edit` because it is already there.

Comment: hi @vivekpansara I have changed /edit to /editc then also 405 error is coming.

I have  : 

<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editc" method="POST" id="editForm">

Comment: hi @student-17, where is the mapping for `/admin`?

Comment: ok refer the next answer post. and tell me where is the problem. @vivekpansara

Comment: Hi @vivekpansara  

visit this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251983/request-method-post-not-supported-in-spring-mvc   to all your required information to help me