# Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, httprequest, httpresponse, http-response-codes

This is My form :

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editc" method="POST" id="editForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

This is My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "User edit Form - Database Interaction");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName("editpage");
    System.out.println("getting edit page");

    return model;

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/editc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateCredentials() {
//      System.out.println("Username= "+username+"  password= "+password);
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Credential Edit Operation");
    model.addObject("message", "You are successfully updated your credentials");
    model.addObject("edited", "TRUE");
    model.setViewName("editpage");
    System.out.println("executed updateCredentials POST method");

    return model;

}
```

Now the issue is I am getting 405 error in console like below:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
 WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Can any one please help me resolving this error ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the posted code. Something else is going wrong. its difficult to say where it might be wrong. To debug further, is your get call working fine? if so when the server starts up, it will spit out the request mapping details. Check to see if the mapping is bound to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your java method is wrong, you need to add also what you are expecting from the POST. Have a look in to this [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) to correct your code.

Comment: Do you mean the  @ModelAttribute(...) annotations  @daniele . I had it before and it was not working at that time

Comment: I mean the same signature of the @damien answer and also you should add another handler for the GET. Note that for the POST handler you need to accept a parameter of a class which has the fields of the form

Comment: It is not necessarily true to have model attribute as argument to your controller method.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @minion

Answer (score 0):

You first need a GET method to display the form and a POST to submit it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/editc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateCredentials() {
    return new ModelAndView("editPage");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/editc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateCredentials(@ModelAttribute UserCredentials credentials) {
    someService.save(credentials);
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi @Damien recheck the question i have the Get method.

Comment: But your post method doesn't contain any attribute value. Your form will try to find a handler that take a structure with what is in your mode, like in my example where UserCredentials object would contain a username and a password String fields.

Comment: Even if i added that means for username & password it was not working then I tested by removing those parameter.